# Check input is not empty on submit click after that show another div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new to jquery, I have sign up form with 4 input fileds. On submit button it should check required fields.
After checking required fields it should show another div. I have paste my html & jquery code here. Pls hekp me to resolve this.

thanks in advance

```
    <form class="login-form">
   <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label>Email</label>
<input type="email" class="form-control" required="required">
  </div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Mobile Number</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required">
</div>
 <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label>Password</label>
 <input type="password" class="form-control" required="required">
</div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label>Confirm Password</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" required="required">
  </div>
  <div class="forgot-password-text highlight-text bl">
  Already have an account? Back to Login
   </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary form-control createac" type="submit" id="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
  </form>
```

My jquery

```
    $('#signupbtn').click(function () {

    if ($('.signupform').find(':input').length > 0) {

        return;
    }


    $('.login-translate-container').css("transform", "translateX(-720px)");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the type button to 'button':

```
<button class="btn btn-primary form-control createac" type="button" id="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
```

Then:

```
$('#signupbtn').click(function () {

  $('input').each(function() {
    if(!$(this).val()) {
      alert('Some fields are empty');
      return false;
    }
  });

  $(".signupform").submit(function () {
    $('.login-translate-container').css("transform", "translateX(-720px)");    
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below mentioned solution. I suggest you to use jQuery Validation Plugin

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#loginForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }).validate({
        rules: {
            mobile: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            confirm_password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                equalTo: "#password"
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            mobile: "Please enter mobile number",
            password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            },
            confirm_password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
                equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
            },
            email: "Please enter a valid email address"
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var $form = $(form);
            var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
            var serializedData = $form.serialize();
            console.log(serializedData);
            $inputs.prop("disabled", true);
            $('.login-form').slideUp('fast');
            $('#anotherDiv').slideDown('slow').removeClass('hidden');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.hidden{
display:none;
}

.error{color:red;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id="loginForm" class="login-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Mobile Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="forgot-password-text highlight-text bl">
        Already have an account? Back to Login
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control createac" id="signupbtn" value="Sign Up" />
</form>

<div id="anotherDiv" class="hidden"> Another Div after submit</div>
```

This will help you, Let me know if it not works for you.

Comment: Ok, But i dont want to use jQuery Validation Plugin